# Does the verb "stitch" need preposition for specification?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

As a learner I use the verb **stitch** without any prepositions / adverbs, like:

> I need to **stitch** the rip in my shirt.

Today I read:

> ...**stitch** it **up** and **stitch** it **down.**

Do **up** and **down** here shows only the direction of movement of the **needle?**

Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> ...stitch it up and stitch it down.

In usage, these examples (up and down) do not show the direction of movement of the needle.  These two idioms are understood to mean "repair" [up] or "secure" [down] something that needs closing or tightening.

"I need to stitch it up before I can wear this torn shirt."

"The shirt pocket is falling off, so I will stitch it down."

It could be used to show needle movement with further clarification, such as in sewing instructions; but even there, the pronoun "it" would not ordinarily be used.